# Почему меняется arr после range с append?

Tags: golang

Code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    arr := [...]int{0, 1, 2}
    for i := range arr {
        fmt.Println(i, ":", arr, arr[:i], arr[i+1:], "::", append(arr[:i], arr[i+1:]...))

    }
    fmt.Println("arr :", arr)
}
```

Output:

```
0 : [0 1 2] [] [2 2] :: [1 2]
1 : [1 2 2] [1] [2] :: [1 2]
2 : [1 2 2] [1 2] [] :: [1 2]
arr : [1 2 2]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что `append` не обязательно создаёт новый отрезок, а использует существующий, если у него достаточная ёмкость. В Вашем случае `append` просто копирует данные, используя исходный отрезок.

Отрезок (слайс) - всего лишь структура вида

```golang
type slice struct {
    arr *T
    len int
    cap int
}
```

Где `arr *T` это указатель на массив типа T (т.е. того типа, какого и отрезок, в Вашем случае int). При этом ёмкость каждого из отрезков будет ёмкостью до конца исходного отрезка

```golang
arr := [...]int{0, 1, 2}
for i := range arr {
    fmt.Println(cap(arr[:i]), cap(arr[i+1:]))
}
```

```
3 2
3 1
3 0
```

https://play.golang.org/

И, таким образом, `append`, смотрит на ёмкость первого отрезка - если её достаточно, чтобы поместить новые значения, то новый отрезок (а точнее, новый подлежащий массив) не создаётся, а используется исходный.

В Вашем случае ёмкость первого отрезка всегда 3, а новых значений вместе с исходными всегда столько, что они умещаются в эту ёмкость.

---

[Go Slices: usage and internals](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals)